# How can a add the delete item functionality in my Android app?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I would like to implement the same technique as used in the stock android photos app to delete pictures. What I mean by that, is that I would like to be able to select the pictures / items when perform a long item click. Then the actionbar should also display how many pictures I have selected. If you know the app, you will also know what I mean.

Basically what I have so far, is the action bar itself (I am using the appcompat one) and the gridview. There I will have add this functionlity somewhere in here:

```
private void setGridViewClickListener() {
    mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {

            File imgFile = new  File(mImagePaths.get(position));
            if(imgFile.exists()){

                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                zoomImageFromThumb(new View(mContext), myBitmap);
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a `ChoiceMode` to `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL` to your gridview and a `MultiChoiceMode` listener:

```
gridview.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
gridview.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener());
```

Then create an `ActionMode` ([Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.html)) in this listener with these methods (*I added a few example*):

- `onPrepareActionMode`: clear the menu, inflate the menu
- `onCreateActionMode`: clear menu, inflate.. or whatever
- `onItemCheckedStateChanged`: update the title in the ActionBar (like +1 item string), re/set a background to the clicked view..
- `onActionItemClicked`: retreive the id clicked and perform actions (as  `notifyDataSetChanged` method)
- `onDestroyActionMode`: update the activity (like reset the background for views)

This tutorial: [Multiple Selection GridView in Android](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/04/26/multiple-selection-listview-android/) might help you to do this. Also see the [Guide Topic](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) in **Enabling batch contextual actions in a ListView or GridView** section.

Hope this helps.